# Creating bubble charts with ggplot2

Tags: r

I have the following results which I would like to translate to a bubble graph:

Data for bubbles:

```
stockA = 0.39 (38/99)
stockB = 0.18 (18/99) 
stockC = 0.68 (68/99)
For y axes frequency scale from 0 - 70
```

and for x axes until 99

The numbers of y axes is the numerator of fraction and the x axes is the denominator of fraction.

How is it possible to make a plot like [this one](http://khakieconomist.com/2012/09/making-cool-bubble-charts-in-r-structural-unemployment-edition/) enter image description here Are these data enough to make this plot?

data points for x and y axes and size for bubble

```
x,y,size of bubble
126, 54, 5.3
57, 60, 9.1
57, 43, 0.5
424, 53, 11.5
62, 44, 5.0
30, 32, 1.4
28, 33, 4.9
```

Comment: each stock (data point) should have a value for the x-axis, y-axis, size of bubble, and color of bubble in order to be similar to the link you've provided. `ggplot2` can do this with various aesthetics on a `geom_point`. Give it a try and if you run into problems, update your question with the data and the code you tried and we can help.

Comment: @cory thank you for your comment. I add  x-axis, y-axis, size of bubble values as a first step. I will try to make some things with code. If it is possible easy any kick start help for the chart will be very helpful for me because I am new in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.
I named your data.frame "a" (next time use dput for easier import to R)

```
a
    x  y size
1 126 54  5.3
2  57 60  9.1
3  57 43  0.5
4 424 53 11.5
5  62 44  5.0
6  30 32  1.4
7  28 33  4.9 

ggplot(a,aes(x,y))+geom_point(size=a$size)
```

Produces

[image]

Of course, ggplot will let you play with all the layers as usual. Also, you might want to check the Google package for making bubble charts googleVis. But ggplot2 is good enough for many reasons. Just add more columns if you want more customization.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will test it and I will come back with more data and an update with more code. thank you again